# Substituting a dependency module with a compatible replacement

Tags: gradle-kotlin-dsl

In Gradle Groovy DSL you can easily [substitute a dependency module with a compatible replacement](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/customizing_dependency_resolution_behavior.html#sec:module_substitution) as explained in the [Gradle user manual](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/userguide.html). How do you do the same in Gradle Kotlin DSL?

Comment: Also opened an [issue](https://github.com/gradle/kotlin-dsl/issues/898) at the project's github.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had also opened an [issue](https://github.com/gradle/kotlin-dsl/issues/898) at the project's github, which was answered by Github user [eskatos](https://github.com/eskatos). I coded and executed his answer and found that it also works. Here is his code.

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency {
        if (requested.name == "groovy-all") {
            useTarget("${requested.group}:groovy:${requested.version}")
            because("prefer 'groovy' over 'groovy-all'")
        }
        if (requested.name == "log4j") {
            useTarget("org.slf4j:log4j-over-slf4j:1.7.10")
            because("prefer 'log4j-over-slf4j' 1.7.10 over any version of 'log4j'")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

### TLDR

The example from [Gradle docs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/customizing_dependency_resolution_behavior.html#sec:module_substitution) in Gradle Kotlin DSL

```
configurations.forEach({c: Configuration ->
    println("Inside 'configurations.forEach'")

    val replaceGroovyAll: DependencyResolveDetails.() -> Unit = {
        println("Inside 'replaceGroovyAll'")
        if (requested.name == "groovy-all") {
            val targetUsed = "${requested.group}:groovy:${requested.version}"
            println("Replacing 'groovy-all' with $targetUsed")
            useTarget(targetUsed)
            because("prefer 'groovy' over 'groovy-all'")
        }
        if (requested.name == "log4j") {
            val targetUsed = "org.slf4j:log4j-over-slf4j:1.7.10"
            println("replacing 'log4j' with $targetUsed")
            useTarget(targetUsed)
            because("prefer 'log4j-over-slf4j' 1.7.10 over any version of 'log4j'")
        }
    }
    c.resolutionStrategy.eachDependency(replaceGroovyAll)
})
```

### Details

Gradle's `ResolutionStrategy.eachDependency` accepts an argument of type `Action<? super DependencyResolveDetails>`. [Since version 0.8.0](https://github.com/gradle/kotlin-dsl/blob/master/doc/release-notes/0.8.0.md#updates-since-v070) Kotlin Gradle DSL transforms `Action` to a [Function literal with receiver](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#function-literals-with-receiver). So whenever you need to pass an `Action<T>` in a Groovy Gradle script, you can define it in Kotlin as a

```
val funcLit: T.() -> Unit = {
    // fields and methods of T are in scope here
}
```

Then you can pass this `funcLit` as an argument wherever an `Action<T>` is expected.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. It did work as expected. Thanks also for appropriate links to the Gradle-Kotlin-DSL release notes and Kotlin reference guide.